# Edit breadcrumbs to insert extra step

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs

Magento 2.3.4:

I want to edit the breadcrumbs so that instead of showing `Home > Product name`, they show `Home > Store > Product name`.

How and where should I make modifications?

Comment: You can override breadcrumbs.phtml or you can write plugin for breadcrumbs.php file or follow https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279854/change-breadcrumbs-after-search-product-in-magento-2